# Sonarqube and Jenkins Integration with I/O Exception

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

We have a Enterprise SonarQube and Enterprise Jenkins already in place and the respective configuration in Jenkins exists. I have created a stage in my Jenkinsfile as shown below.

```
        stage('Sonarqube') {
        environment {
            scannerHome = tool 'SonarQubeScanner'
        }
        steps {
            withSonarQubeEnv('Enterprise Devops Sonar') {
                sh "printenv"
                sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner"
            }
            timeout(time: 10, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true
            }
        }
    }
```

This however throws some errors like it cannot install specific required modules. Here is the error log

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:990)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1388)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1400)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:167)
at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:863)

Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to install https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/sonar-scanner-cli/4.5.0.2216/sonar-scanner-cli-4.5.0.2216.zip to /tmp/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/SonarQubeScanner
at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:937)
at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:850)
at hudson.tools.DownloadFromUrlInstaller.performInstallation(DownloadFromUrlInstaller.java:77)
at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:69)
at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:109)
at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:206)
at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation.forNode(SonarRunnerInstallation.java:91)
at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation.forNode(SonarRunnerInstallation.java:49)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ToolStep$Execution.run(ToolStep.java:152)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ToolStep$Execution.run(ToolStep.java:133)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Without using the environment block, I once just printed the env to debug and it is configured correctly.  Also the config at Jenkins Management was done as per the documentation.

I am still figuring it out how to overcome this.  Any pointers here would help.

Comment: It looks like, sonar-scanner is not getting downloaded or installed from maven central repo. I guess in Jenkins under `Global Tools Configuration` you have selected to install sonar-scanner automatically. If it is not getting downloaded, you can manually download the sonar-scanner and keep it in any folder in the path `/var/lib/jenkins/` and then provide the path of sonar-scanner home in `Global Tools Configuration`

Comment: If you use maven, you can use sonar scanner with maven plugin : https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/

Comment: I've had a weird issue where had to force a similar example with `tool name: 'SonarQubeScanner', type: 'hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation'`, never actually found out the exact reason and also the error that I was having was different from yours, but well, give it a try.